# Too many React components re-rendering, how to limit it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am generating a list of components on the screen like so:

```
const MessagesContainer = ({ messages, categories, addHandler }) => {
    const options = categories.map(category => (
        { value: category.name, label: category.name }
    ));

    return (
        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
            {messages.map(message =>
                <div key={message.id}>
                    <MessageEditor
                        message={message} 
                        options={options}
                        addHandler={addHandler}
                    />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const MessageEditor = ({ message, options, addHandler }) => {
    const [modifedMessage, setModifiedMessage] = useState(message);
    const [isAdded, setIsAdded] = useState(false);
    
    const textClass = (charLimit - modifedMessage.text.length) > 0 ?
        'text-success' : 'text-danger';
    const buttonClass = isAdded ? 'danger' : 'primary';

    const ref = useRef(null);

    const textAreaHandler = textArea => {
        const copiedMessage = { ...modifedMessage };
        copiedMessage.text = textArea.target.value;
        setModifiedMessage(copiedMessage);
    };

    const addButtonHandler = () => {
        const add = !isAdded;
        setIsAdded(add);

        let selectedCategoires = ref.current.state.value;
        // Firing this handler results in ALL the MessageEditor
        // componets on the screen being re-rendered
        addHandler(modifedMessage, add, selectedCategoires);
    }

    return (
        <div className="d-flex flex-column message-view-container ml-5 mr-5 mb-5">
            <div className={`message-count-container ${textClass}`}>
                {charLimit - modifedMessage.text.length}
            </div>
            <Select
                ref={ref}
                placeholder="Tags"
                isMulti
                name="tags"
                options={options}
                defaultValue={[options[0]]}
                className="basic-multi-select select-container"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                isDisabled={isAdded}
            />
            <Form.Control
                style={{
                    width:350,
                    height:220,
                    resize:'none'
                }}
                className="mb-1"
                as="textarea"
                defaultValue={message.text}
                onChange={textAreaHandler}
                disabled={isAdded}
            />
            <Button variant={buttonClass} onClick={addButtonHandler}>
                {isAdded ? 'Remove' : 'Add'}
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

And the parent component that holds the `addHandler`:

```
const { useState } = require("react");

const Messages = () => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [saveMessages, setSaveMessages] = useState({});

    const addHandler = (modifiedMessage, add, selectedCategoires) => {
        const copiedSaveMessages = { ...saveMessages };
        if (add) {
            if (selectedCategoires) {
                selectedCategoires = selectedCategoires.map(item => item.value);
            }
            copiedSaveMessages[modifiedMessage.id] = {
                text: modifiedMessage.text,
                tags: selectedCategoires ? selectedCategoires : []
            }
        } else {
            delete copiedSaveMessages[modifiedMessage.id];
        }

        // This results in every single MessageEditor component being
        // re-rendered
        setSaveMessages(copiedSaveMessages);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {categories &&
                <div>
                    <div className="ml-5 mr-5 mt-5">
                        <MessagesContainer
                            messages={messages}
                            categories={categories}
                            addHandler={addHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            {Object.keys(saveMessages).length > 0 &&
                <div>
                    <Image 
                        className="upload-icon"
                        src={uploadIcon}
                    />
                    <div className="text-primary count-container">
                        <h2>{Object.keys(saveMessages).length}</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

The issue is that if I hit the add button an trigger `addHandler` it causes all the `MessageEditor` components to re-render. And the performance is very slow if I have a few hundred components on the screen.

I guess this is because the `saveMessages` state variable belongs to the `Messages` component and `MessageEditor` is a child of `Messages` so it also re-renders.

Is there an approach I can take to update this state without causing all the other components to re-render?

Comment: Can you create a sandbox issue? Would be better to measure performance for tangibility?

Answer (score 0):

In `Messages` you should wrap your `addHandler` in a `useCallback` hook ([React useCallback hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)) so that it is not re-created at each render.

```
const addHandler = useCallback((modifiedMessage, add, selectedCategoires) => {
    // function body...
}, []);
```

Additionally, you can also memoize `MessageEditor` using `React.memo()` ([React memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)).

```
const MessageEditor = React.memo(({ message, options, addHandler }) => {
    // component body...
});
```

Comment: What would the dependency on `useCallBack` be for the `addHandler`. It has a dependency array and I'm not sure what to put in it.

Comment: @Kex According to the documentation, you should pass all the callback arguments, therefore `[modifiedMessage, add, selectedCategoires]`

Comment: That doesn't work. Consider: `const addHandlerCallback = useCallback(addHandler, [modifiedMessage])`, Get the error `modifedMessage is not defined`

Comment: @kex, that is not the correct syntax; you should have: `const addHandler = useCallback((modifiedMessage, add, selectedCategoires) => { // ... function body }, [modifiedMessage, add, selectedCategoires]);`

Comment: I still get the undefined error. You are trying to pass the function parameters to the dependency array. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: My apologies, I misread your code. In your case the function parameters are not props therefore your callback has no dependency; you should pass an empty array as second parameter. I updated my answer n order to reflect the amendment.